# How to replace Toast message by Intent in below code?

Tags: android, android-toast

This is the code in which I want to change this one Toast message into 3 Intent. How can I do so:

```
 @Override
   public void onClick(int buttonIndex) {
   Toast.makeText(
              parent.getContext(),
               "On click " + circleSubButtonTexts[buttonIndex],
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

Comment: Could you explain in brief

Comment: Please explain more about your question..

Comment: I have floating menu with three images. When I click those image, a toast message is shown but instead of that i want to go to 3 different activities

Comment: did you try google searching how to use intents?

Comment: Your floating buttons is in Activity ? @Anish

Comment: Welcome to the community. Try searching for your code in the Android docs, try some ideas out, and come back with specific coding problems. Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

By this much of your question I can help you by below code only.
Try with below code , set `clickListner` on  `FloatingActionButton`

```
 FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_1);
    fab1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have created and registered your activities to the manifest, (and you have access to application), simply replace the content of above function with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
// Add data or something
startActivity(intent);
```

For more details: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html